# HAVING clause should return type BOOL, but returns INT64 at [24:3]

Tags: sql

```
select 
    warehouse.warehouse_id,
    CONCAT(warehouse.state, ': ', warehouse.warehouse_alias) as warehouse_name,
    count(orders.order_id) as number_of_orders,
    (select
      count(*)
      from warehouse_orders.orders orders)
      as total_orders,
    case
      when count(orders.order_id)/(select count(*) from warehouse_orders.orders orders) <= 0.20
      then "fulfilled 0-20% of Orders"
      when count(orders.order_id)/(select count(*) from warehouse_orders.orders orders) >= 0.20
      AND count(orders.order_id)/(select count(*) from warehouse_orders.orders orders) <= 0.60
      then "fulfilled 21-60% of Orders"
    else "fulfilled more than 60% of orders"
    END AS fulfillment_summary
from warehouse_orders.warehouse warehouse
left join warehouse_orders.orders orders
  ON orders.warehouse_id = warehouse.warehouse_id
group by
  warehouse.warehouse_id,
  warehouse_name
HAVING
  count(orders.order_id >0)
```

I'm learning SQL on google analytics. I followed everything from instructor.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: By the way, in a CASE expression, when the first WHEN tests for `<=0.20`, then the second WHEN doesn't need to check for `>=0.20` - just check for `<=0.60` as you already *know* it is *not* `<=0.20`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

`HAVING count(orders.order_id >0)`

should be corrected to

`HAVING count(orders.order_id) > 0`